# Determine the primary colors of a rendered webpage?

Tags: css, browser, image-processing, rendering

Does anyone know if there exists either an algorithm for (or an implementation of) a system that would, given a full website (with HTML, CSS, images, etc), determine the "primary color palette"?

By "primary color palette", I mean that if a human designer were asked to come up with the "most prominent colors" in the site's design they would be able to write down the top 4 or 5 colors.

I imagine it would be implemented by using a rendering engine like webkit (or perhaps a full browser instance) to render the given assets correctly, then perhaps "screen capture" the results and do some sort of pixel-color + area analysis. Or perhaps there would be some smarter way to analyze things with CSS?

The use case for something like this would potentially be for folks like [getsatisfaction.com] that use Javascript to inject elements into the page. They could potentially style these elements ahead of time so they fit in with the page better.

Thanks!

Comment: The usual additive primary colours are Red, Green and Blue.  The usual subtractive primary colours are Cyan, Magenta and Yellow.  I suspect you use the term 'primary color' to denote something other than either of these lists -- you should explain what you mean.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thanks for your response, I've edited my question to try and more clearly express that I'm looking for a "color palette" from the webpage.

Comment: I think only a screenshot-based approach would work. Parsing HTML + CSS and determining how it would look is a pretty tall task. Finding code for an image color histogram would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site will take a URL and output the color scheme.

[Color Combos](http://www.colorcombos.com/grabcolors.html)

Comment: Oh very interesting--thanks! I'll try it out and see how well it works. It looks to be CSS based so I imagine sites that have large images as part of their design won't be captured correctly.